# How to automatically format Python files in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]I'm very confused about how it automatically format code in VS Code.

Below is a very clean, brand new environment for using Python.

When I write a test.py and press Save, prompt me for this information in the lower right corner, but I have installed these globally.

I had read this [Automatically reformat Python code in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901525/automatically-reformat-python-code-in-vs-code) . However , I can't comment it.

My workspace `settings.json`

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\admin\\anaconda3",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
  "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
  "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
  "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "[python]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: you need to install the formatter to be able to use it. Just click "install" on the prompts

Comment: If prompts do not appear, you can do this by navigating to the "Extensions" tab (CTRL+Shift+X) and searching for Python.

Comment: The location where `pylint` et al. are installed, is that in the global `PATH` variable?

Comment: @md2perpe yeah,I'm sure pylint、flake8、yapf are in the global. Instead, they do not exist in the project local environment（conda interpreter）

Comment: @Cheese The code has a red prompt but cannot be formatted automatically

Comment: @Blackgaurd yeah, I had globally install the lib that prompt , set the plugin（ms-python.python）using it

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the extensions you installed do not contain formatting extensions. You just need to click "Install" according to the prompt in the lower right corner. Of course, I suggest your adding the following two lines to the setting.json file so that you can format it automatically when editing and saving.
    `"editor.formatOnType": true, "editor.formatOnSave": true,`